# Как разместить 3D-модель на сайт?

Tags: веб-программирование, 3d

Добрый день.
Возникла проблема, изложенная в названии.

Есть ли какие то не сильно заумные способы? :)
Спасибо!

Comment: С помощью каких инструментов Вы хотите решить данную задачу?

Comment: Интереснее всего был бы вариант прямого размещения модели (допустим, формата .obj или .3ds) в качестве виджета на сайт, используя JavaScript.

Comment: Отрендерить в AVI или GIF . Если геометрия статична просто в текстуру и как картинку отобразить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. WebGL - поддерживается не всеми браузерами, но зато без доп софта
2. Флеш - есть у всех, неплохо рисует 3D
3. Silverlight, есть у многих, неплохо рисует 3D
4. Unity - почти ни у кого нет :)

Comment: Silverlight, есть у многих?.. Вы с паралельной вселенной что-ли? :D

Comment: Статистика стима говорит про больше чем 60%. 
Правда 3d нет в моно, поэтому win/mac only.

Answer (score 1):

[Beauty-3D.com](http://beauty-3d.com) с его помощью можно отображать OBJ 3D модели на сайте. Там все по пунктам расписано что и как делать, на сколько я понимаю он работает на FLASH, поэтому проблем с отображением быть не должно